# Show suggestion bar in iOS 8 custom keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

Is this possible to enable suggestion bar in custom keyboard same as in attached snapshot. If not then I will have to create custom bar so I will have to increase height of the keyboard. Do you have code to increase the height of keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try: (`viewDidAppear` is method of `UIInputViewController` subclass)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];

    CGFloat _expandedHeight = 250;
    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant: _expandedHeight];
    [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
}
```

**WARNING**: write in **`viewDidAppear:`** method

It is not working. Logs:

```
2014-10-01 17:10:38.532 Coloured[7232:308451] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79829970 V:[UIInputView:0x79b2f660(250)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79824ea0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIInputView:0x79b2f660(216)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79829970 V:[UIInputView:0x79b2f660(250)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Make sure you tried it in `-viewDidAppear:`. And should NOT edit my post to show log (should comment instead of)